# Make imported steam folder work with new win10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, steam

my old pc had win7 and I had a Steam folder with my games inside.

I moved the disk drive to the new pc with win10, but now the steam folder is read-only. If I uncheck the atribute, a progress bar appears, does some stuff with the steam folder, I click ok when it's done, but if I close and reopen the property panel, the read-only flag is back.

I want that win10 owns the steam folder like I  created within the new system. How do I do that? How do I tell win 10 process the permissions in a way everything works later?

Here some screenshots:

[image: property panel]
[image: permissions]

Someone can help me fix the permissions?

EDIT: this is what doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you add the folder to steam as a location?

Comment: @StevenDavison The folder *is* the steam folder. Steam itself works ok, even a couple of games do, but most of them, when I try to start them, give a "permission denied" error.

Comment: Go back to the permissions screen, and tick the box "Replace all child...." and see if Steam can access the files then. When I get home, I'll check what permissions are assigned on my Steam Folders

Comment: On the Advanced Security settings screen, take ownership of the main folder (G:\steam). Then make sure your login has the correct permissions, presumably you want "full control", check off "replace all child object permission entries ... (etc)" and apply it.

Comment: As Brian said you must take the ownership of the steam folder, else a less proper solution would be to give "full Control" to "Administrators" (which includes you)..

Comment: As far as I can see, I am the owner since I am an administrator. Other non-steam folders that work fine have the same owner as this. Does steam run with another user even if I launch it?

Comment: The (blurred)\administrators group owns it. As long as the users group/administrators group for your current machine have full control (assuming the blurred name is your PC's name/SID) you shouldn't have problems, follow my prev post if you do.I'm not sure what you mean in your original post when you say "I want that win10 owns the steam folder". The "filled" read-only box means there are files within the folder that might be marked as read only, a check would mean everything within is read only. That's the expected behavior. What is the actual issue here? What isn't working?

Comment: Based on your update I'm almost sure that the blurred portion is the SID from your old machine, and taking ownership and reapply permissions will fix it.

Comment: The blurred part is the name of my computer yes, but the old and the new machine had the same identical name, so I don't know if it's the old one or the new one.

Comment: None of the Security Principles (names shown in the Principle column) are unrecognized by the OP's OS. If they were, the Principle name would be shown as a SID instead of a translated name. Well-known security principles such as `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`, `Everyone`, etc. use the same SID *no matter which computer created the permissions* and therefore are enforced universally, i.e., even on totally unrelated machines. Only unique principles (e.g. `MyOwnUser`) would not be recognized on another box.

Comment: *now the steam folder is read-only* ... Actually, that may not be the case. All folders will show the read-only checkbox partially filled in like yours is. Try it: Create a new folder, then observe it's set the same way. If you want to see whether there are any Read-only files in the folder, from an Elevated Command Prompt run `dir /ar /s` while in the Steam folder. Any read-only files will be shown. To remove the read-only attribute from all files in the Steam folder, run `attrib *.* -r /s`, again from within the Steam folder.

Comment: [You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-folders-in-windows-server-2003,-in-windows-xp,-in-windows-vista-or-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After telling windows to own the folder (even if the screenshot shows that the admin already owned the folder) I was able to use the folder like I wanted. I don't exactly know what was wrong, but imposing the ownership fixed the issue, it seems.